# Bash: Save --output file into variable or array?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

With `curl`, for example, I would like to use the `--cookie-jar` option to save the cookies into a variable or array that can be used later in a script. By default the `--cookie-jar` option tries to save the cookies to a local file. I would like to do something like this to keep the script self-contained:

```
$ curl --cookie-jar $cookies 'https://duckduckgo.com/'
```

Then:

```
$ curl --cookie $cookies 'https://duckduckgo.com/'
```

Is this possible in Bash?

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Can you explain what `/proc/$$/fd/0 ` is? I've never seen that used as an output path before

Comment: `/proc/$$/fd/0` is stdin. `$$` is a special variable that expands to the current process id. `fd` stands for *file descriptor*. By the way, the suggested command does not work. I don't even understand why it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying `-` as the output file writes to stdout. The output can be assigned to a variable as usual: `var="$(command)"`. However, this would still include the webpage. To only store the cookies you would have to output the webpage to a file using the `-o file` option. Example:

```
cookies="$(curl --cookie-jar - stackoverflow.com -o webpage.html)"
echo "$cookies"
```

I'm not sure if it is possible to assign the webpage and cookies to separate variables reliably in bash without using any files. Here are some ugly approaches:

- Parse the output and split at the line `# Netscape HTTP Cookie File`.
  **Problems:**

  1. The webpage or cookies could contain that line too, so we would split at the wrong location.
  2. The webpage and cookies could be interleaved.
- Run `curl` twice. In the first run, only store the cookies. In the second run only store the webpage.
  **Problems:**

  1. The webpage could behave differently for each run.
  2. Running `curl` twice is inefficient.

To read the cookies with `--cookies` it would be best to emulate a file rather than passing the cookies as a string argument. You can specify `-` as a file again and read from stdin or use bash's `<()` syntax:

```
curl --cookie - stackoverflow.com <<< "$cookies"
curl --cookie <(printf %s "$cookies") stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: @Sorowi, sorry, this isn't working for me. Did you test this?

Comment: Did you run `var="$(command)"` literally? Of course `command` was only a placeholder for the `curl` command. I tested my suggestion as seen in the edited answer. My `curl` version is 7.58.0.

Comment: @Socowi He probably missed the need for `-o`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it working with `cookies="$(curl -s --cookie-jar - 'https://stackoverflow.com' -o /dev/null 2>&1)"; echo "$cookies"`. Still playing around with it in my script

Comment: Interesting.. with `--cookie $cookies` in the following curl command, curl just hangs. It doesn't complete the request. Any ideas?

Comment: @vskbdvds First of all, you should quote the variable: `"$cookies"`. If that doesn't help pass the variable over stdin or a pseudo file, see the edited answer for examples.

Comment: @abdan `-s` will still output the webpage to stdout.